# In Google Analytics How do you assign a page value in behavior, site content, all pages?

Tags: google-analytics

In Google Analytics How do you assign a page value in behavior, site content, all pages?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Page Value is supported if you are using e-commerce transactions. The Page Value tells you whether a page contributed to your site's revenue.

For example, if someone always views a Gala Details page before purchasing tickets, the Gala Details page will contribute to your site's revenue as shown in the Page Value. Even though they aren't purchasing something on that page, they are still going through that page to purchase something.

You can find the complete description of [Page Value here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2695658?hl=en).